# Recommendations for anchoring long rope swings

Tags: safety, ropes, knots

Some questions about rope swings similar in size to the the [corona arch swing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4B36Lr0Unp4) which has an accompanying [setup video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rm6pd-uvMeA).

- Assuming you can avoid rope abrasion, do swings like this damage
  climbing ropes? Swing goes straight into a pendulum with no/limited free fall.
- The figure eights get very tight at the anchor. I've
  heard people say you should loosen them, retie them, or cut them away
  after several jumps. Any truth to this?
- We set up a prussic
  chord at the anchor. It attached just below the figure eight
  knot that secured the jump line. This kept the weight
  of the jump partially off the knots. Are there risks associated with
  this - eg. can prussics weaken a system like this, or cut the rope?
- We also jumped onto a prussic (primary), with an atc below, with
  overhand knot below that. We clipped the bite from the overhand knot
  to our belay loop. We did this because we jumped with a backpack and
  had to rapel to the ground after the swing completed. Slightly clustered, but we wanted to easily rapel after the jump was
  completed. Any feedback on this setup?

[EDIT] Removed some slang

Comment: This is an interesting question, but a bit unclear. Please clarify the following:
"It bit just below the figure eight knot";
"(primary)";
"clipped the bite from the overhand knot";
"A bit clustered".
I think these are typos or slang; don't know for sure.

Comment: Probably "bite" = "bight"

Comment: "It bit just below the figure-eight". In this case, "bit" is the past tense verb of the verb "bite" which is "to use teeth to cut into" which I suppose is slang for the action which friction knots (prusiks) use when grasping. I intend it to mean that is where the prusik 'attaches' to the jump rope.

In the case of "a bit clustered" this is "bit" as in "a small quantity." Basically what I mean here is that your belay loop has four carabiners on it and so it is hard to understand easily and slightly hard to clean when setting up the rapel.

Comment: Potentially better to split this into multiple questions?

Comment: A [bowline](http://www.animatedknots.com/bowline/#ScrollPoint) is a good option other than a figure 8. It doesn't tend to jam as much and (provided it's tied correctly) is just as strong

Comment: @Liam A bowline can untie when not in tension which is extremely relevant for a jump like this. You'd need at least a double bowline, though that is still significantly weaker in cross load as shown in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSms2k2eV3Y

Comment: Providing you add a good "tail" and a stopper it shouldn't come undone. Remeber bowlines where THE tieing in knot not that long ago. A double bowline is a good option for extra safety

Comment: I've seen that video before and I don't rate it. There are no tails, stoppers & the loading is unrealistic.

Answer (score 6):

> Assuming you can avoid rope abrasion, do swings like this damage climbing ropes? Swing goes straight into a pendulum with no/limited
>   free fall.

I can't see it doing any special damage to the rope that wouldn't occur through climbing. I would make regular inspections of the rope and retire/replace equipment when necessary. The fall factors involved are well within the 1.7 tested by the UIAA but it might be worth contacting the manufacturer of the rope to see if they have any information about how the ropes perform in the pendulum type fall rather than a straight one.

> The figure eights get very tight at the anchor. I've heard people say you should loosen them, retie them, or cut them away after several
>   jumps. Any truth to this?

If you can't untie them then I guess you'll have to cut them. If this is happening regularly than maybe you can prevent it by undoing and retying so they aren't getting repeatedly tightened with each jump. I'd say if you can untie them then you don't need to redo them, your just adding more opportunities to make a mistake. If you find that the rope is becoming deformed or the sheaf is getting damaged then that part of the rope is no longer safe and should be cut out.

> We set up a prussic chord at the anchor. It attached just below the
>   figure eight knot that secured the jump line. This kept the weight of
>   the jump partially off the knots. Are there risks associated with
>   this, eg. can prussics weaken a system like this, or cut the rope?**

A figure of 8 is a very [efficient](http://caves.org/section/vertical/nh/59/Rescue%20Knot%20Efficiency%20Revisited.pdf) knot, retaining about 80% of the ropes strength. I don't know of any figures that show the efficiency of a adding a prussic to a rope but I doubt it is making the system stronger. It is also just another way to add a point of wear to the rope. Lastly what are the prussics attached to? surely loading the weak prussics instead of the strong rope is not desirable. I would personally avoid doing this.

> We also jumped onto a prussic (primary), with an atc below, with overhand knot below that. We clipped the bite from the overhand knot
>   to our belay loop. We did this because we jumped with a backpack and
>   had to rapel to the ground after the swing completed. Slightly
>   clustered, but we wanted to easily rapel after the jump was completed.
>   Any feedback on this setup?

Again is the prussic on your harness directly loaded in the fall? You want to give yourself the widest safety margin you can so that would look more like clipping into a figure of eight with a carabiner designed to avoid cross loading. Prussics and ATC on the harness ready to use once you come to a stop.

*Caveat:* This isn't **the** way to swing on a rope more a critique of your current set-up from a climbing perspective.

Comment: We just sort of combined climbing knowledge with conjecture and doubled things up when in doubt. I feel like everybody just focuses on the anchor in other online discussions; but then when I went to actually set things up I found there were many other sources of doubt in the system. Is there a "best way" to set up a swing like this?

Comment: @Kenn You really need to split your questions up. This follow up question of how to setup an ideal swing system is a great question. Almost any single question you put in the question at the top is a good question that should stand on its own. You will also get more answers when you split them up. Now one needs to have an answer to every single aspect in order to write up an answer, however many people will have valuable inside on at least one of them. Please split the question up, aaaaargZombies's answer can be ported.